# perform sum from an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sum

If for example I have the numbers 930 stored in the the cells of an array as 9 3 0, 18936 stored in the cells of an array as 1 8 9 3 6 how do I make a sum function that would add 9+3+0 = 12 or 1+8+9+3+6 = 27, a function that would check the length of the array first to check there is no empty cells and then will do the sum. in c

Comment: you will not get any already written code here, but suggestions on the code that you have written or tried to write..

Comment: Post some code (basically any attempt that you've made) and you'll get a lot of help.

Before you spend too much time on it, I'll point out there is no out-of-the-box function to give you the size of an array; you must manage and keep track of that yourself

Comment: Yes, use `strlen` and `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic concept.  I'll let you hash out the details

```
for (idx = 0; idx < some_max_variable_that_you_have_determined; idx ++)
{
    sum += your_array[idx];
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did here                                           for (k=0; k < count; k++){
  sum += array2[k];
} but it isn't working correctly may be I am not determining the count correctly, how can I use strlen do determine the length of the array to get the correct count.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this with an integer array.  It works for character arrays because it continues until it finds a null-terminator ('\0').  The concept just isn't there for an integer array.  How are you creating your array?  If it's static, just save your allocation size.  If you take input from the command line to fill it, or read it from a file, then keep a counter as you add items

Comment: that's what I did I'm taking a record as I add a value to the array like in a new cell    while(temp){
      temp=temp/10;
      factor = factor*10;}
   count = 0;
  while(factor>1 ){
      factor = factor/10;
      
       array2[k] = newnumber/factor;
   /*tocheck number*/   printf("digits of even: %d\n", array2[k] );
        newnumber = newnumber % factor;    
           count++ }  

for (k=0; k < count; k++){
  sum += array2[k];
} @don shankin